# Can't open Software Center / 404 Not Found with apt-get update

Tags: updates, apt, appcenter

[image]Hello, I seem to be having trouble with opening Software Center, when I click on it nothing happens, I'm new to elementary OS and Linux. I think I did something wrong when I tried to update a repository.

I get a lot of "**404 Not Found**" when I run "*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade*", it ends with "*E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.*"